Duda para crear cuenta contable padre e hija, con SQL y PHP
Estoy tratando de crear un catálogo de cuentas contable con PHP y MYSQL.
He visto que algunos sistemas contables tienen su catálogo de cuentas contable de la siguiente manera:

Insertar la cuenta contable con su cuenta hija manualmente, es muy facil:
INSERT INTO `catalogo_cuentas` (`cuenta_padre`, `nombre`, `cuenta_hija`) VALUES ('105002000', 'Clientes extranjeros', '105002000');

La duda que tengo es si con estos sistemas contables obligan al usuario a crear la cuenta_padre asi como tambien la cuenta_hija. ¿O sera posible que el usuario solamente insertar la cuenta_padre y un trigger se encarga de insertar la cuenta_hija?
Y si un triger se encargara de insertar la cuenta_hija podrian dar un ejemplo, por favor.

No sé si será igual en todos lados o países, pero siempre que veo cuentas contables el número menor es el padre, tú lo tienes al revés. En todo caso, para que alguno se cree automáticamente necesitas el nombre de la cuenta

Saludos. A salvedad yo entendiera erróneamente tu planteamiento; no creo sea un proceso automático; necesitas indicar tanto el numero de la cuenta como su descripción; y en tal caso quien está debajo... lo más probable es que sea un catálogo precargado con datos ya predefinidos (sea hecho a mano o por algún script)

Para mi esto está basado en opiniones, pero, la cuenta padre, podría nunca tener una hija, y del mismo modo, tener muchas hijas, entonces la cuenta padre debería ser el numero menor y el que manda.

Lo he pensado y no se puede. Es como las clases, una clase hija puede convertirse en una clase padre pero no a la inversa, porque la clase hija tiene más datos que la padre. Aquí es casi lo mismo, desde una cuenta podrías crear una cuenta padre (sabiendo de antemano las reglas de la estructura árbol que estas usando y dejando el nombre vacío o con un nombre provisorio). Y ahora que lo recuerdo, todas las veces que he trabajado con cuentas contables, siempre las agrego todas del día de uno, porque es una lista conocida

Puedes verlo desde otra óptica. Para empezar, entiende las cuentas como cadenas de caracteres en lugar de entenderlo como números.
Como cadena de caracteres, puedes ver la cadena como una unión de microcadenas con dígitos, en nuestro caso tres subcadenas de tres dígitos:
Los tres primeros dígitos como grupos de cuentas (en el caso que propones "102","105"...) Los otros dos o tres como cuentas padre (el tu caso 001) y los otros tres como subcuentas contables (001,002,...,999)
Así pues el número de cuenta es una cadena compuesta que se crea mediante el programa en cuestión que lo ejecuta (PHP, Perl, Python...) y se lo manda al motor SQL como una cadena de 9 dígitos.
El proceso de creación también pasa por un proceso previo (programado también con su lenguaje correspondiente) de comprobación de si existe(n) la cuenta(s) padre. Si existe(n), solamente crea la subcuenta, si no existe(n), crea previamente las cuenta(s) padre,
Espero que me haya sabido explicar y te ayude.

Es conveniente tener la cuenta junta  en un solo campo con los 9 digitos, o separar cuenta, subcuenta y sub sub cuenta cada una en diferente campo?.     Asi: |102001002|? o asi, |102 | 001 | 002 | ?        lo pregunto por aquello de reportes de estados financieros basicos y reporte de auxiliares contables.     gracias por la ayuda!
